# jQuery data function returning the first value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a one span tag with data attribute, `data-kr-id`. On clicks of different items of the list, I update this span's `data-kr-id` attributes and it gets updated.

When for the `first time` I retrieve this(`data-kr-id`) value using jQuery's `data` method, I get the correct value. But from the subsequent time, I always get the same value as of the first time. But on using jQuery's `attr` function, I get the correct value. Can't figure out why.

**CODE: Where I set the `data-kr-id` value:**

```
$_applozicWtLauncherBtn.attr('data-kr-id', seller.UserId);
```

CODE: **Where I retrieve the values:**

```
 var topicId = $applozic(this).data("kr-id");
 topicId = $applozic(this).attr("data-kr-id");
```

In the above code where I retrieve values, using `data` method gives me old value(the value of the first item I retrieved), but using `attr` method gives me correct value.

**UPDATE** :

> As informed by everyone, I was setting the data attributes with `attr` method and retrieving the value with `data` method. After using `data` method for setting the attribute, When I was retrieving the values, I was getting a getting empty string. After digging a bit deeper, `I realized there are two different versions of the jQuery are being used here`.
>
> Sorry for the incomplete information and late update.

Comment: Because you're explicitly setting `data-kr-id`. `jQuery.data`

Comment: can I see ther section wher you assign " $_applozicWtLauncherBtn " to your element

Comment: Why are you setting them with `attr`? `.data()` is designed to handle that for you. I might be misremembering, but I think jQuery actually stores the data in an object in memory rather than directly on the DOM like `.attr()`. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

You set value only using `attr`, Second time when you set `data-kr-id` value using `attr` then data value remains same, so need to set value with `data` also

```
// With Attr
$_applozicWtLauncherBtn.attr('data-kr-id', seller.UserId);
// With Data
$_applozicWtLauncherBtn.data('kr-id', seller.UserId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually jquery's `.data()` fetches value from the property (same as `.prop()`) not from attributes. Main difference is `.attr()` fetches data from HTML tag which you can see it will reflect on your HTML when you update it with `.attr()`. But when you use `.prop()` or `.data()` it will not reflect in HTML tag but it will update value in it's property for that HTML tag as per the DOM tree.

You'll find out more about [difference property and attribute from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).
Initially this property will set when your element is created. So for the first time your `.data()` and `.attr()` will work fine. When you update value from `.attr()` it will manipulate DOM but property will be remain same.